# I can't gett and "Out of office" message for emails sent automatically in Exchange Online

Tags: email, exchange, exchangeonline

I've got a request from one of the users. The situation is like this: The User receives an email daily from address A. He wants this to be delivered to distribution group B. This works no problem with either rules set on exchange server (by admin) or set by user from his OWA.

The thing is, the user doesn't receive the "Out of office" response, when that message is sent. Doesn't matter if the rule forwards it or adds the group to recipients. Is there any way to set the rule, that would deliver him an information, that user C from group B has an automatic reply enabled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the OOF setting on DL member will not works when send message to DL. It's by design.

Moreover, we can configure message forwarding with multiple methods, and its **behavior** is different for each other.
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/timmcmic/2015/06/08/exchange-and-office-365-mail-forwarding-2/

Answer (score 1):

Short answer. No. However this site doesn't like short answers, so I have to type some more text, but the answer is still no.

Comment: You could add that since OOO is a type of rule, if rules triggered OOO messages then you could have two mailboxes just sending OOO back and forth to each other until the server crashes. So that's kind of a reason why. Generally automatic processes shouldn't fire off other automatic processes when it comes to e-mail.